What is the complexity of this tree recursive integer replacement algorithm?
LeetCode has an Integer Replacement problem defined as follows:

Given a positive integer $n$, you can apply one of the following operations:

If $n$ is even, replace $n$ with $n / 2$.
If $n$ is odd, replace $n$ with either $n + 1$ or $n - 1$.

Return the minimum number of operations needed for $n$ to become $1$.

I would like to determine the time and space complexity of a naive tree-recursive algorithm that uses memoization (caching to avoid recalculation). Here is the Python implementation:
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = {1: 0} # specifies 1 as the base case requiring 0 operations

    def integerReplacement(self, n: int) -> int:
        if n not in self.results:
            if n % 2:  # n odd
                self.results[n] = 1 + min(
                    self.integerReplacement(n + 1),
                    self.integerReplacement(n - 1)
                )
            else:  # n even
                self.results[n] = 1 + self.integerReplacement(n / 2)

        return self.results[n]

If this were tree recursive in all cases, the running time would be $O(2^n)$ because the branching factor is two; however, this is tree recursive only half the time. What is the time complexity of this algorithm? I am also interested in the space complexity, which I know would depend on the greater of the maximum stack depth and hash table size.

I figured out the answer to my question. The time complexity is $O(\log(n))$ because $n$ is halved every two calls (worst case). For more detail, see my solution.

Here, you can get away with branching in only one direction greedily. Thus, you can even convert the recursion into a simple while loop, which takes about $O(\log n)$ steps. Here is the code:
int integerReplacement(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    if (n == INT_MAX) {
        return 32;
    }
    while(n > 1){
        count ++;
        if ((n & 1) == 0) { // n is even
            n = n >> 1; // n = n/2
        } else { // n is odd
            if ((n & 2) == 0 || n < 4) { // 2nd last bit is zero or n is small
                n--; // n = n - 1
            } else {
                n++; // n = n + 1
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

If $n$ is odd, then adding or subtracting $1$ makes it even, which will then be halved. If we somehow anticipate whether adding or subtracting will make it a multiple of $4$, then we would rather go in that direction.
Now if $n~ mod~ 4 = 1$, then subtracting helps, whereas if $n~ mod~ 4 = 3$, then adding helps. By 'helps' I mean, you can perform (at least) two successive halvings. Thus we have an optimal greedy strategy at our hand.
For added effciency, I have converted the $mod$ operations into equivalent bitwise operations.

Now let us analyze your algorithm:
Here we have $$T(n) = \begin{cases}
T(n+1) + T(n-1) + c, & \text{when $n$ is odd}\\
T(n/2) + c, & \text{when $n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$
Combining these two steps, we have $$T(n) \le T(\frac{n+1}{2}) +  T(\frac{n-1}{2}) + 3c$$
Thus, we have $T(n) = O(n)$.

You can see my solution there: https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-replacement/solutions/5215070/a-simple-greedy-solution

Thank you very much for your time and explanation, but what I'm looking for is a complexity analysis of my code. I will edit my question to make that clearer.
